# Null ID and Insert as a child of a document using WebAPI

Tags: c#, mongodb, hierarchy, webapi

I'm using MongoDB and I've designed my model as follows, now I have two problems:

1. When I insert the child manually in the document, the ID of the child set to `null`
2. How can I insert document as a child of a document using WebAPI?

> ```
> public class Building
> {
>   [BsonId]
>   [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
>   public string Id { get; set; }
>   public string Name { get; set; }
>   public bool IsUpdating { get; set; }
>   public ICollection<Telephones> Telephones { get; set; }
>   public ICollection<Building> Childs { get; set; }
> }
> ```

In my controller class, I've following method:
[HttpPost]

```
public IActionResult Create(Building Building)
{
    _BuildingDb.Create(Building);
    return CreatedAtRoute("GetBuilding", new { id = Building.Id.ToString() }, Building);
}
```